# Creating pencil style strokes/lines in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

I’m trying to recreate a pencil style stroke in Sketch, akin to the pencil brush in Illustrator, has anybody been able to do this or know of a plugin that would assist?

I’m using Sketch for wireframing and really want to emulate the scratchy, pencil like lines you see in programs such as Balsamiq. Why not use Balsamiq? We don’t have an account at work and the the pseudo low fidelity mocks that Balsamiq lets you create are useful for managing stakeholders here (in that they get it is a conceptual wireframe).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Dashed lines are the only line modifications available besides color, position, and thickness.

I did try to do something like that with jagged-edged rectangles (manually created), but resizing always made it look bad.